# node.js stream file upload structured for folder

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, stream

Im doing a little CMS for my site using node and express.
and i want to use a form positng multiple files, and store those files into public/image/:foldername.

so i have created a form and it has two inputs:
1.event -- which is the event name
2.file -- which is the files input obvisuly

now when the admin log in and sees this form he is typing his event name for example"
"birthday"
and the image files associated with it.

eventully i want the strcure to be like this:
public/
 /image
  /birthday
   image1
   image2
   image3
   image4

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary spacer3">
    <div class="row">
        {{#if error}}
        <div data-alert class="alert-box">
           {{error}}
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center">
            <h1>פאנל ניהול</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="/login">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns rtl">
                  <label>שם משתמש</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="שם משתמש" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns rtl">
                  <label>סיסמא</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="סיסמא" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                  <input class="button [radius round]" type="submit" value="התחבר" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the route:

```
app.post('/upload',routes.photos)

exports.photos = function(req, res){
    console.log("body " + req.body);
    console.log("event " + req.body.event);
    console.log("files " + req.body.files);
    if (req.body && req.body.files && req.body.event){
        //event i th the name of the event
        //files is the files that needs to be uploaded
        var file = fs.createReadStream(req.body.files);
        var newfile = fs.createWriteStream('./public/img/images');
        file.pipe(newfile);
    }
    else{
        console.log("none")
    }
};
```

the readstream and the writestream isnt working, and i dont know how to make this strcture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be

```
<form method="POST" action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

also

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(req.body.files);
```

should be

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(req.files.formName.path);
```

Where formName is

```
<input type='file' name='formName' />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what iv done:
installed mkdirp from npm
mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
this will create a new folder.

and readFile will read those images.

```
exports.photos = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files)
    console.log(req.files.img_file);

    console.log("Uploading File");

    fs.readFile(req.files.img_file.path, function (err, data) {

      var newPath = __dirname + "./public/img/albums";
      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
        res.redirect("back");
      });
    });

};

//Post request to create new album
exports.createAlbum = function(req, res){
    if (req.body && req.body.album)
        var album_name = req.body.album;
    else
        var album_name = 'unknown_album-' + (parseInt(Math.random() * 5) + 1);

    console.log(__dirname);
    mkdirp('./public/img/albums/' + album_name, function (err) {
        if (err) 
            console.error(err);
        else 
        {
            console.log('Folder created.');
            res.render('admin/panel', {
                title: 'אדמין',
                message: 'תיקייה נפתחה בהצלחה',
                album: album_name
            });
        }
    });
};
```